# Can the triangle inequlity extened to show the distance inequlity of a trapezium

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

[image]

$AB // CD$. What are the angle conditions  (acute, obtuse or right angle) of $a,b,c,d$ to be satisfied the inequality $ |AB+BC| > |CD|$?

$AB,BC,CD$ are distances.

Comment: I can't say I have much insight on this question, except that I expect the parallelogram law to be helpful in this situation.

Comment: @Orangutango do you have any ideas?

Comment: @Norman Sorry I misinterpreted your question. I don't think there are any simple conditions.

Comment: @CalvinLin how about some theory about parallelograms? Will that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BI think the inequality holds iff $a+\frac{b}{2}<180$. Let $P$ be a point on $AB$ where $B$ is between $P$ and $A$ such that $PB=BC$. Also Let $Q$ be the fourth vertex of parallelogram $APCQ$ that lies on $CD$ (or its extension). The desired inequality holds only when $D$ is between $C$ and $Q$ which translates to the angle inequality I mentioned.

Comment: that is not clear. How do you prove that $a + 0.5b <180$

Comment: by doing that,  for me clear that $AB>CD$ still not clear that $AB+BC>CD$?

Comment: $CQ=AP=AB+BP$ and $AP=AB+BC$ iff $PB=BC$ not $PB=PC$ therefore Let P be a point on AB where B is between P and A such that PB=BC?

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I meant $PB=BC$. I'll correct the answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9670/discussion-between-norman-and-s-b)

Comment: so $P\hat BC= 180-b $
and $B\hat PC=B\hat CP=b/2$
and $P\hat CD=c+b/2>B\hat AD=a$
so $c+b/2 > a$
so how did you get your answer ?
$a+b/2<180$

Comment: Let's remove some of the previous comments as it seems it's getting too long. About your point, you can use the fact that $b+c=180^\circ$ to reach what I said.

Comment: how do you say that $b+c=180^\circ$

Comment: It's a basic consequence of $AB$ and $CD$ being parallel.

Comment: but ABCD is a trapezium not a parallelogram?

Comment: Check [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoid#Characterizations). Right at the beginning of your question you yourself mentioned that $AB$ is parallel to $CD$.

Comment: Still not clear. So you were saying that $b+c=180^\circ$, then similarly can we tell $a+d=180^\circ$ so I am  confused.

Comment: And that is also correct. Are you familiar with axioms of plane geometry? These are very basic facts obtained from the axioms.

Comment: not at all. Any way then starting with $b+c=180\circ$ how do you ended up with $a+b/2<180\circ$?

Comment: Look up your comment from 2 days ago, you did it up to $c+b/2>a$. Now set $c=180^\circ -b$. That's it.

Comment: So bad. I miss that. thanks